# Disable (or) Prevent cursor placement in ASP Read Only textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

In my solution, there's one ASP.NET ReadOnly textbox. When clicking on it, the blinking cursor is inserted which causes the user to believe that they can edit.

Could anybody please suggest me the best approach to avoid this?

I tried many approaches but of no use.

Comment: Must it be a `TextBox`? You'll find `blur()` workarounds though it won't be foolproof - e.g. IE11

Answer (score 1):

The following approach will remove the Blinking cursor right after the texbox gets focus:

```
<asp:TextBox onFocus="this.blur()" 
             ID="TextBox1" 
             runat="server" 
             ReadOnly="true" 
             Text="This is a test!">
</asp:TextBox>
```

On any TextBox just add **onFocus="this.blur()"**

> This approach utilizes the **HTML DOM [Blur()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp)** method: The blur() method is used to remove focus from an element.

**Caution:** *Using Blur() may not work under [Internet Explorer 11](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14595)*.. Thanks to @EdSF observation.

I suggest you use a **Label** instead, because this way there is no Blinking cursor or a cursor, period!

```
<asp:Label   ID="Label1" 
         runat="server" 
         ReadOnly="true" 
         Text="This is a test!" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" />
```

When using a *Label* you probably have to apply some CSS to make it look like a *TextBox*. You can also **Disable** the TextBox. However, you may have to apply CSS to make it NOT looked disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur approach. . Even I have used the same. .actually I don't want to disable the textbox ad it will effevt the readability of text inside it. .

Comment: By using this blur () method onclick attribute of textbox,  I' m losing the focus of that. . I mean my asp read-only textbox is in ajax modal popup extender. . So if I click on textbox and fire the blur () method, I' m losing the focus of that popup. . I needed to be on the popup itself. .  That's what I need. .!!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the enabled attribute to false on the textbox?  It would like like:

```
<asp:Textbox Id="textbox1" runat="server" Enabled="False" Text="Text">
```

The text will appear in the text box and you could still highlight the text but you can't place the cursor in the box.  You could set the enabled property from the code behind as well if you wanted the status to change to true at some point.

Comment: Thanks a ton for ur approach. . If I disable the text box, the readability of text inside the textbox would be effected.  . So I don't want to do that... and coming to label,  my client would not prefer to be shown as a label..he wanted to be shown as a textbox without allowing cursor to be placed in it. .